# Random probability error

Tags: bash, shell

I decided to make a program using `bash` to make a magic eight-ball thingy, and I was having some problems can anyone help me?

```
n = $RANDOM
printf "Ask a yes or no question: "
read question
printf "Enter a number: "
read number
printf "Enter another number: "
read number1
equal = `$number * $number1`


if [ "$equal" -lt "$n" ] then
    printf "Yes"
else
    printf "No"

fi
```

Comment: ahmm.This is not batch file core but rahter bash

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! can you elaborate on the "problems"? What does the terminal output when you run this? People are less likely to answer your post if they have to run your code to find them.

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Ok I'll remember that next time and thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do something like this:

```
printf "Ask a yes or no question: "
read question

if [ $RANDOM -gt 16383 ]; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Comment: Why did you choose `16383` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl because $RANDOM gives you a number between 0 and 32767, so there's a 50% chance it will be greater than 16383.